# Visual Studio Code Personal Extension Marked Obsolete

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I made a Visual Studio code extension (PL/SQL) awhile back for myself that I installed locally. I am guessing with one of the latest versions, extension handling has changed. My local extension keeps getting marked as obsolete, I am guessing since it is not 'registered' in the extension marketplace.

Is there a way to flag it 'valid' locally so I can use it without having to register it? I do not plan on making the extension public. I have tried deleting the .obsolete file in the extensions folder, but it gets recreated over time. I have tried changing the true value to false in the .obsolete file for my extension, but that also gets changed back over time.

Comment: What's the minimum engine version you stated in the package.json file? Raise that to a more recent version and fix any error coming up because of using an obsolete/deprecated API. The obsolete marker has nothing to do with the fact that you only installed your extension locally.

Comment: engine specified in extension's package.json is: vscode: ^1.55.0. I am currently using VS Code 1.80.0. I updated accodingly and will go from there. Where will errors be raised? Is there a log file generated or in the VS Code console itself?

Comment: You will get build errors when you try to debug your extension.

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I created my own Visual Studio Code Extension and recently started having the same issue and found this page looking for answers.

After investigating other extensions installed on my profile, I noticed a consistent theme across all of the `package.json` files as well as here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#example for the `"publisher"` key value. **None of the values have spaces!**

In the `package.json` I set the `"publisher"` key to a value that included spaces a few days ago and reloaded VS Code without issue. However, when I closed VS Code completely and reopened, my extension was added to the `.obsolete` file every time.

Solution that worked for me:

1. I removed all spaces from the `"publisher"` value in the `package.json` for my extension.
2. Closed VS Code
3. Removed my extension from the `.obsolete` file again
4. Modified the publisher portion of the `"id"` value in the `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\extensions.json` file connected to my extension (removed the spaces).
5. Reopened VS Code

VIOLA! It no longer added my extension to the `.obsolete` file and has since been working as expected.

Not sure if you have the same issue with the same key but its worth checking the other keys for values that do not support spaces (not sure which ones but for sure `"publisher"` does not).

Comment: Hey @amorenojr, thanks for the response and more importantly the manifest. That was helpful, I was missing the publisher key/value pair in my package.json. I did not register my extension so I do no not have the "id" value you mention in step 4. I was kind of hoping to not have to register it. I added a "publisher" key/value pair since it is required and removed the obsolete file. Will monitor results

Comment: @McRivers, glad you found it. If you're using the extension privately, adding the publisher key does nothing except give VS Code something to tie the package to the extentions loaded into VS Code. I bet you got it.

Comment: silly question, but can this key be something i make up or does it need to be generated registered with VSC extension market?

Comment: @McRivers, I believe it can be anything so long as the value does not contain spaces. Be sure to remember that what ever you set the value to, you must also make sure that same value is called in the `id` of the `extensions.json` file.